# PostgreSQL Locking Behavior w/ Partial Index

Tags: postgresql

For PostgreSQL, will `create index foo on bar where condition=true`, i.e. without `concurrently`, lock an entire table for a partial index?

Or will only the affected rows, i.e. `where condition=true` be locked?

I did not see it spelled out in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createindex.html.

Answer (score 0):

The lock taken is on the table level.  It doesn't lock a specific WHERE clause.